# Why sawtooth curve on file handles and cpu usage on our kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are having an interesting *file handles* and *cpu* usage behavior on our Kafka Cluster that I cannot explain :) I'm not sure which information would be needed to figure out the reason, so I will list some (tell me if you are missing any):

- 3 nodes in the cluster
- all topics are replicated three times
- ratio between delete / compacted topics is about 50/50 with a retention time of 7 days
- delete topics (~16) mostly with 1 partition
- compacted topics (~20) mostly with 16 partitions
- all use topics default settings

In addition, we have 4 compacted topics (1 partition) with a very small *segment_ms* and *retention_ms* set to 1 minute. This topics are used as cache to serve the latest values.

Here is a metric showing the sawtooth behavior:

[image]

The file handle spices are about 7 days long and also seem to relate to the cpu usage. The default *segment_ms* (which we use for the majority of our topics) is 7 days long. Not sure if this relates.

Any ideas why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this interesting behavior is caused by our "compacted" topics. We replaced almost all "compacted" topics with "delete" and only kept those 4 that are really mandatory (as caching). Now the behavior is back to normal (as you can see for the last couple of days).

[image]

In Kafka, a topic consists of segments. A segment is only "garbage collected"  once the last entry is gone. If a topic is compacted, there might be single entries (without further updates) blocking the whole segment from being "garbage collected" which leads to many "open file handles". With "delete" segments are garbage collected more constantly.